# make np.vectorize return scalar value on scalar input

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-ufunc

The following code returns an array instead of expected float value.

```
def f(x):
    return x+1
f = np.vectorize(f, otypes=[np.float])
>>> f(10.5)
array(11.5)
```

Is there a way to force it return simple scalar value if the input is scalar and not the weird array type?

I find it weird it doesn't do it by default given that all other ufuncs like np.cos, np.sin etc do return regular scalars

**Edit**:
This the the code that works:

```
import numpy as np
import functools

def as_scalar_if_possible(func):
    @functools.wraps(func) #this is here just to preserve signature
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        return func(*args, **kwargs)[()]

    return wrapper

@as_scalar_if_possible
@np.vectorize
def f(x):
    return x + 1
```

print(f(11.5)) # prints 12.5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The result is technically a scalar as its shape is `()`. For instance, `np.array(11.5)[0]` is not a valid operation and will result in an exception. Indeed, the returned results will act as a scalar in most circumstances.

eg.

```
x = np.array(11.5)
print(x + 1) # prints 12.5
print(x < 12) # prints True, rather than [ True]
x[0] # raises IndexError
```

If you want to get a "proper" scalar value back then you can just wrap the vectorised function to check the shape of the returned array. This is what numpy ufuncs do behind the scenes.

eg.

```
import numpy as np

def as_scalar_if_possible(func):
    def wrapper(arr):
        arr = func(arr)
        return arr if arr.shape else np.asscalar(arr)
    return wrapper

@as_scalar_if_possible
@np.vectorize
def f(x):
    return x + 1

print(f(11.5)) # prints 12.5
```

Comment: So apparently A[()] does the trick also, without an if. source: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32766210/making-a-vectorized-numpy-function-behave-like-a-ufunc?rq=1. I am choosing this and closing because apparently there is no built-in way to do this, only this hack. Thanks!

Comment: In ways `np.vectorize` itself is a hack.  It's built on `np.frompyfunc` returns an object dtype array.